# Is my iOS app work if it's base sdk is iOS 7 and downloaded to iOS 8 device?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8

I submitted my application to App Store and it will be released in 4-5 days. I used Xcode 5 and iOS 7 as Base SDK. What happens if an iPhone user downloaded my app to his iPhone with iOS 8? Does it still work as an iOS 7 app?

I try to run my app on Xcode 6 and iOS 8 simulator. And it's not working because some of the changes related to SDK methods.

Is it work exactly like an iOS 7 app, on iOS 8 device?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You've had the last three months to test this yourself. Install iOS 8 GM on a development device and see how it works. Only you can determine if it works or not.

Comment: @maddy but i used iOS 7 as base sdk. Should it run as an iOS 7 app on iOS 8 device?

Comment: In theory it will work but it may have some issues. But you need to do it. Run your iOS 7 app on an iOS 8 device. FYI - there are apps in the store built with a Base SDK of 2.0 that work today. But every app is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't used any super specific things it should work fine. It will be scaled on the new iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus though. You should update your app with new App Icon and Launch Screen Images and adjust your UI to the new sizes.

Comment: Every app does "super specific things". That's kind of meaningless. A virtually useless app could have problems. Saying it "should work fine" is far from ideal. The app must be tested to know for sure.